# Angular HttpIntercept issues after npm link

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a lib that contains an class `HttpInterceptor`. After performing the procedure with the `npm link`, from this lib to my project, the entire request that passes in `event instanceof HttpResponse` `returns false`. When I run a `console.log (event)`, it returns an object of type HttpResponse.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        LoadingService.show();
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap( (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse){
                    LoadingService.hide();      
                }                
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                LoadingService.hide();
                return throwError(event);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `npm link`, copy paste the output folder of your lib in your project's `node_modules` directly. Doing this will return true for `HttpResponse` checks

```js
event instanceof HttpResponse 
// returns true
```